# itext component over another component

Tags: itext

I'm creating a pdf report with itext and I'm having a problem. I create a line separator and immediately below I create a pdfTable. The problem is that de top border of the table is over the line separator I just created. Is any way to down a couple of lines in order to draw the next component with itext and solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the API documentation of the [`PdfPTable`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html) class. You'll fond methods such as `setSpacingBefore(float spacing)` and `setSpacingAfter(float spacing)`. In you case, you could something like:

```
table.setSpacingBefore(6);
```

This will introduce a spacing of 6 user units (which by default corresponds with about 1/12 of an inch) before the table.

The spacing you need for "a couple of lines" depends on the leading. The default fonts size is 12 and the default leading is 1.5 times the font size. Two lines would be (2 x (12 x 1.5)) or 36 user units (about half an inch).